# RStudio is not picking my latest R version

Tags: r, rstudio

I need help to point my Rstudio to different R version installed on my host machine. I have 3 R versions installed on my machine.

**R-3.6.2**

**R-3.6.3**

**R-4.0.2**

But my Rstudio is always picking **R-3.6.2** only.

I want to use **R-3.6.3** . Can somebody please suggest where can I make changes?
My all binaries are pointing to R-3.6.3 on the server itself but not sure where RStudio is picking R-3.6.2?

like all below are pointing to R-3.6.3:

```
/bin/R
/usr/local/bin/R
/usr/bin/R
```

Rstudio configs:

```
]$ cat /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf
# Server Configuration File
rsession-which-r=/bin/R
```

```
]$ cat /etc/rstudio/rsession.conf
# R Session Configuration File
rsession-which-r=/bin/R
```

```
]$ cat /usr/lib/rstudio-server/VERSION
1.2.5033
```

I don't see any option in Rstudio UI to select the R version manually like few online docs suggests that.

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop?mobile_site=true. And check .libPaths()

Comment: if you are windows, type Rstudio on the search button, and then instead of clicking on the application to open it, press Control + Enter, This will give you the option to choose the R version you want to run. Select the version and continue to the application. If on Mac, I believe the procedure should be the same except you will press command + Enter instead

Comment: Look at what `echo $PATH` shows.  The R you want should be in an entry before the others you do not want. Similar to what @Christoph menioned for `.libPaths()` (which is for packages, not itself).  R is a command, so the first one found may be used.

Answer (score 6):

In RStudio, go to the tab **Tools > Global Options > R general**> then there is option to select which R version you have downloaded.

Comment: Hi @H.Cheung I tried that option already, but unfortunately we don;t have any option to select R version from there (maybe it's not there in Rstudio Version 1.2.5033).

I only see:

```R session```

and option to set **Default working directory**

Comment: Hi Nitesh. You may be right i'm using "Version 1.3.1056". It appears in the R session R version screen. Sorry couldn't be of more help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by pointing R executable to /usr/local/bin/R